# How work with multiple EntityManager with sonata Admin symfony 2

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

I have a project that connects to three different databases and I want to connect my sonata admin with the three entity managers dynamically.

I tried to manually fill "sonata_doctrine_orm_admin" but that does not work. I found that it is necessary to use `setModelManager`, but I don't know how I can use it.

So, how can I use `setModelManager` to fulfill my needs?